# With more labelled samples in a grouped dataset, to check the correlation with another, is it better to duplicate samples or take the means?

Tags: correlation, mean, dataset, duplicate-records

Another issue is that dataset with more labels in groups, they have less deviation intra groups vs inter groups. So I could take the means of them (the 'second' index), or the whole label means (the 'first' index). Here are examples with randomly generated values (so they don't show any correlations). Here is what a larger dataset could look like.

```
first  second
bar    287       1.618547
       287      -0.607839
       287      -2.262949
       287       1.620212
       454      -1.304819
       454      -1.347689
       454      -2.347092
       454      -2.501167
baz    808      -0.290363
       808       0.292866
       808       2.161479
       808       0.251631
       13       -0.556330
       13       -0.669658
       13       -1.788050
       13        0.226576
foo    399      -1.117241
       399      -0.756117
       399      -1.176926
       399      -1.217614
       194       1.698150
       194      -0.179264
       194       0.754277
       194       0.266544
foz    503       0.220758
       503       1.916860
       503       0.828609
       503       1.044181
       788      -2.082913
       788      -0.586535
       788      -1.960880
       788      -0.734894
```

And then a smaller dataset.

```
bar   -0.942299
baz   -1.537918
foo    0.622322
foz   -0.540513
```

To get correlations between the float values, should I duplicate samples in the smaller dataset? Either to the level of groups or labels of the other, depending on if I should take the mean of the groups. Or should I just take the mean of the labels in the bigger dataset? Or maybe I should take the median actually, since the groups vary, within the labels?

Note: the measurements are of completely different things, that's why they are in two datasets. The correlation is between the float values, indexes are not variables. You can think of the datasets as aspects of humans, where the larger dataset has groups of humans. The labels are resulting outcomes, which may have a correlation from different measurements.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What are you correlating with what? In the smaller dataset, I see a categorical and a numerical variable, you can't calculate correlations on that. In the larger dataset, one variable is repeated multiple times. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You don't see where I call them indexes?

Comment: I see that some variables are called "indexes". I still unfortunately do not understand what you want to do.

Comment: indexes are not variables. Correlation is between the floats , I added that.

Comment: Yes, but between *which* floats? You calculate correlations between two vectors of *paired* floats. How do you know which pairs of floats "belong together"?

Comment: The floats from the two datasets are paired.

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa I think the question is clear enough, any more aspects that aren't clear? At least one person thought it was of interest. You can reopen it.

Comment: It is indeed a bit clearer now, thank you. (Yes, one user upvoted it - but please note that three people voted to close as unclear.) I now understand that you have two datasets with measurements, specifically with *repeated* measurements, but one dataset contains more repetitions than the other - and you want to calculate a correlation. I would very much recommend that you edit this kind of TL;DR summary into your post. I will vote to reopen, but other voters will again need to concur, and such a TL;DR will help them make up their mind.

Comment: I would further suggest that you explain what you are measuring and what your grouping and repetition variables indicate, and why exactly you want to calculate a correlation. Why? Because the grouping and repeated measurements (one would typically assume much less variation *within* a group than *between* groups, and this may be far more important than any relationship you could tease out by correlation!) may well be far more important to whatever your substantive question is.

Comment: I added more info, if it's too long to read for someone though, I figure they just shouldn't answer. I already put it in the simplest and shortest way I thought of.

Comment: If it's not reopened, guess I'll try again, thanks for the advice, it's preferable to closures without explicit reasons given.

Comment: "one would typically assume much less variation within a group than between groups", yes, I had written before

"Another issue is that dataset with more labels in groups, they have less deviation intra groups vs inter groups"

I am not interested in group variances, within or between groups, though that may be interesting in some cases, pas pour moi. I'm only interested in relations between total labels.

Comment: I figure if anyone has an answer, they can comment that they can, and say how the question can be worded.